# SupervisorStrategy strategy not respecting maxNrOfRetries

Tags: akka.net

I'm learning Akka.net and am stuck trying to get an actor to restart on failure.

With the following, I would have expected the "child has error" string to display 5 times (maxNrOfRetries), however I only see it once.

Can someone please point out what I'm missing? Is my code wrong, my understanding? Both?

Here is the LINQPad script http://share.linqpad.net/t8x5wl.linq

Thank you

```
async Task Main()
{
    var system = ActorSystem.Create("MySystem");
    var parent = system.ActorOf(Props.Create<ParentActor>(), "parent");

    var child = await parent.Ask<IActorRef>(new GetChild());

    child.Tell(new HelloChild());
    child.Tell(new CauseChildToThrow());
    child.Tell(new HelloChild());
    child.Tell(new StopChild());
    
    await parent.Ask<object>(new EndProcess());
    "fin".Dump();
    
}


public class ParentActor : ReceiveActor
{

    public ParentActor()
    {
        var child = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<ChildActor>(), "child");
        Receive<GetChild>(msg => Sender.Tell(child));
        Receive<EndProcess>(msg => Sender.Tell(new {}));
    }

    protected override SupervisorStrategy SupervisorStrategy()
    {
        return new OneForOneStrategy(
        maxNrOfRetries: 5,
        withinTimeRange: Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
        localOnlyDecider: x =>
        {
            //return Directive.Resume; // skips the bad messsage?
            return Directive.Restart; // retries with the bad message?
        });
    }
}

public class ChildActor : ReceiveActor
{

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        "child prestart".Dump();
    }

    protected override void PreRestart(Exception reason, object message)
    {
        "child pre restart".Dump(reason.Message + " " + message.ToString());
    }

    public ChildActor()
    {
        "child constructor".Dump();
        Receive<HelloChild>(msg => "Child says hi".Dump());
        Receive<StopChild>(msg =>
        {
            "child stopping gracefully".Dump();
            Context.Stop(Self);
        });
        Receive<CauseChildToThrow>(_ =>
        {
            "child has error".Dump();
            throw new MyException();
        });
    }
}


public class GetChild { }
public class HelloChild { }
public class StopChild { }
public class CauseChildToThrow { }
public class EndProcess { }

public class MyException : Exception{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue. The dying actor needed to resend the failing message back to itself.

```
protected override void PreRestart(Exception reason, object message)
{
    "child pre restart".Dump(reason.Message + " " + message.ToString());
    Self.Tell(message);
}
```

Also, i had to remove the call to

```
 child.Tell(new StopChild());
```

Working LINQPad script here http://share.linqpad.net/hv6w4g.linq